# Failed To Install syslinux on USBDRIVE with Mac OS X

Tags: mac, usb

I am creating Ubuntu Server 13.10 Bootable USBDRIVE with command line using Mac OS X, In this i tried to install Syslinux on USBDRIVE by using syslinux command by following:

```
xxx-Mac:~xxx$ sudo syslinux /dev/disk2s1
```

here i am using disk2s1 for my usbdrive but i got following error:

```
-bash: syslinux: command not found
```

What is alternative to install syslinux on usbdrive, Mac OS X dont include any syslinux command?

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't `syslinux` on Mac OS X.
You will have to install it first as described on this blog:
[Creating a bootable USB stick from OSX](http://www.pyrosoft.co.uk/blog/2013/01/09/creating-a-bootable-usb-stick-from-osx/)

The essentials steps will be based on:

- Disk Utility,
- [Syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project)
- [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

The second explains the few basic steps to get and install Syslinux.

Comment: Please summarize the website behind the link. If the link breaks, you post is worthless.

Comment: Right ⇒ done :).

Comment: The maker of unetbootin has a port of syslinux which is distributed with unetbootin in binary form. The repository is located here: https://github.com/gkovacs/syslinux-mac

Comment: @CousinCocaine that's exactly what happened 8 years later...